# Children's picture book with many common fantasy characters acting in a play?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a picture book that I saw perhaps once as a small child (maybe 25 years ago, the book seemed relatively new at the time). Although it was a picture book, it seemed more suited toward rather older children. I don't recall there being much of a story, but instead the book contained detailed illustrations of many fantasy/fairy-tale characters interacting in detailed scenes.

The odd thing about the book was that the characters all seemed to be part of a play on a stage. I recall a director (perhaps one of the three little pigs?) with a megaphone sitting in a director's chair speaking to the characters on the stage. I remember the Seven Dwarves from Snow White were reimagined and made an appearance.

There also seemed to be a subplot with the big bad wolf sneaking his way from scene to scene.

The book very much had a "Where's Waldo" feel, where much time could be spent looking over the many characters and all the things they were doing.

I've scoured the internet and can't find a clue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! The key word that finally resulted in a successful search was "audition."

It is [The Fabulous Fairy Tale Follies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679853162). The book consists of characters auditioning for various parts in a play, and there are clues on each page that hint at which actor will be ideal for the role. You can follow the clues while looking through all the characters to identify the one that meets all the criteria. There is also a running joke throughout the book involving the janitor and his pig who want to have a role in the production.